# Using UIScrollView to "rotate" between three views

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have a `UIScrollView` which I have added three views `Z`, `A` and `B` as such:

[image]

What I would like to accomplish is have the three views be set in a "rotating" manner centered on view `A` appearing first. When a user swipes left and sees view `B`, swiping **left** again gets to view `Z`, and vise versa, swiping **right** when at view `Z` takes the user to view `B`.

I have setup the code for `self.scrollview` as such:

```
ZViewController *zViewController = [[ZViewController alloc] init];
[self addChildViewController:zViewController];
[self.scrollView addSubview:zViewController.view];
[zViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

AViewController *aViewController = [[AViewController alloc] init];
CGRect aframe = aViewController.view.frame;
aframe.origin.x = 320;
aViewController.view.frame = aframe;
[self addChildViewController:aViewController];
[self.scrollView addSubview:aViewController.view];
[aViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

BViewController *bViewController = [[BViewController alloc] init];
CGRect bframe = bViewController.view.frame;
bframe.origin.x = 640;
bViewController.view.frame = bframe;
[self addChildViewController:bViewController];
[self.scrollView addSubview:bViewController.view];
[bViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];

self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(960, self.view.frame.size.height);
self.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

However, presently I am unsure how to proceed in terms getting the "rotation" element to work (i.e. swiping on `B` gets to `Z`) and would appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered searching for examples of `transitionWithView` and `UIView animate...` methods? Also some good articles, for example [ViewControllerTransitions](http://www.objc.io/issue-5/view-controller-transitions.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @andrewbuilder. Just wanted to make sure that I understand - you are suggesting that instead of setting up an actual `UIScrollView` with views inside, that I just have one `UIView` that merely animates to different contents based on swiping?

Comment: Disclaimer: I have not attempted this before so these are only suggestions... Yes I am wondering whether you instead have three view controllers that you transition between. There are a lot of methods to customise view transitions. That may be easier to code and later manage if the views are three separate view controllers. Otherwise you may be looking at writing custom animations for your scroll view. Not that it can't be done, perhaps more difficult to code and then manage.

Comment: I agree with @andrewbuilder, I would use 3 controllers and animate the transition between them. I think using a UITabBarController (with the tab bar hidden) would be a good way to go because it keeps a pointer to all its controllers (so as you move among them, you will be going to the same instance each time). Also, being able to use setSelectedIndex: will make it easy to go to the view you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use 3 view controllers instead of a scroll view with 3 pages, this simple implementation using a tab bar controller should work for you. I started with the tabbed application template, and added a third view controller. The controllers at indexes 0, 1, and 2 correspond to your views A, B, and Z respectively. In the viewDidLoad method of the A controller, I set the tab bar to be hidden.

I created a BaseViewController class that the 3 controllers I setup in the storyboard inherit from. The code in BaseViewController creates and adds the swipe gesture recognizers, handles the swipes in such a way that gives you the rotating sequence, and gives you a slide over transition between the views,

```
@implementation BaseViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swiperRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    swiperRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperRight];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swiperLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipe:)];
    swiperLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft;
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swiperLeft];
}

- (void)handleSwipe:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    if (sender.direction == 1) {
        NSInteger nextIndex = (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex - 1 == -1)? 2 : self.tabBarController.selectedIndex - 1;
        [self slideInViewWithIndex:nextIndex direction:-1];
    }else{
        NSInteger nextIndex = (self.tabBarController.selectedIndex + 1 == 3)? 0 : self.tabBarController.selectedIndex + 1;
        [self slideInViewWithIndex:nextIndex direction:1];
    }
}


-(void)slideInViewWithIndex:(NSInteger) index direction:(NSInteger) dir {
    UIView *nextView = [(self.tabBarController.viewControllers[index]) view];
    [self.tabBarController.view addSubview:nextView];
    nextView.frame = CGRectOffset(self.tabBarController.view.bounds, dir * self.tabBarController.view.bounds.size.width, 0);
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.3 animations:^{
        nextView.frame = self.tabBarController.view.bounds;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.tabBarController.selectedIndex = index;
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apple sample code [StreetScroller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/StreetScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011102)

Github repositories:

- by **Daniele Margutti** [DMCircularScrollView](https://github.com/malcommac/DMCircularScrollView)
- by **Benjamin Guest** [BAGPagingScrollView](https://github.com/bguest/BAGPagingScrollView)

A tutorial

- by **Jacob Haskins** [Objective C – Using a UIScrollView for Infinite Page Loops](http://www.accella.net/objective-c-using-a-uiscrollview-for-infinite-page-loops/)